# SQL select higher than history

Tags: sql

I have a table as follows

```
id   price 
1    100
2    103 
3    101
4    102
5    106
6    107
```

'''

I wanna write a sql command to select those higher than all previous records.

```
1 100
2 103
5 106 
6 107
```

Thank you

Comment: This is not a clear requirement. What does it mean -higher than all previous records?

Comment: the ids were in time sequence. Previous records means records with ids less than current id

Comment: which sql engine are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a NOT EXISTS condition with a co-related subquery:

```
select *
from the_table d1
where not exists (select * 
                  from the_table d2
                  where d2.id < d1.id 
                    and d2.price > d1.price);
```

This returns all rows where no row exists that has a smaller `id` but a greater `price`

Another solution is to use the `ALL` operator:

```
select *
from the_table d1
where price > all (select price
                   from the_table d2
                    where d2.id < d1.id);
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=867728b14f49b3e1f43a6ca65286dd35)

Comment: SPEEDY CODE  THX

Answer (score 0):

For this sample data you can use `MAX()` window function:

```
select t.id, t.price
from (
  select *,  max(price) over (order by id) max_price
  from tablename
) t
where t.price = t.max_price
```

If there are duplicate prices and you want only the rows where the price is greater than all the preceding and not equal to the max preceding:

```
select t.id, t.price
from (
  select *,  max(price) over (order by id rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) max_price
  from tablename
) t
where t.price > coalesce(t.max_price, 0)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=aabf504bae45252ba2979bb732a2736b).
Results:

```
| id  | price |
| --- | ----- |
| 1   | 100   |
| 2   | 103   |
| 5   | 106   |
| 6   | 107   |
```